# Why am I getting Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain Error?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, less

I'm using spring toolsuite to develop an application using spring framework and bootstrap less for styling my site. Now I'm trying to use .border-left-radius(20px); and it is not working. When I use developer tools in Chrome the above error appears:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain: http://127.0.0:8080/app/resources/css/less/bootstrap.less
```

The line that fetches this file is:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="<c:url value='/resources/css/less/bootstrap.less' />" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value='/resources/js/less-1.7.0.min.js'></c:url>"></script>
```

Please Help!! I've been looking for 5 hours now. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I'm including the response body that chrome displays in Network Tab of Developer Tools:

```
// Core variables and mixins
@import "variables.less";
@import "mixins.less";

// Reset and dependencies
@import "normalize.less";
@import "print.less";
@import "glyphicons.less";

// Core CSS
@import "scaffolding.less";
@import "type.less";
@import "code.less";
@import "grid.less";
@import "tables.less";
@import "forms.less";
@import "buttons.less";

// Components
@import "component-animations.less";
@import "dropdowns.less";
@import "button-groups.less";
@import "input-groups.less";
@import "navs.less";
@import "navbar.less";
@import "breadcrumbs.less";
@import "pagination.less";
@import "pager.less";
@import "labels.less";
@import "badges.less";
@import "jumbotron.less";
@import "thumbnails.less";
@import "alerts.less";
@import "progress-bars.less";
@import "media.less";
@import "list-group.less";
@import "panels.less";
@import "responsive-embed.less";
@import "wells.less";
@import "close.less";

// Components w/ JavaScript
@import "modals.less";
@import "tooltip.less";
@import "popovers.less";
@import "carousel.less";

// Utility classes
@import "utilities.less";
@import "responsive-utilities.less";
```

But the error still shows in console and .border-left-radius() isn't working.

Comment: Usually this happens when the less file is inaccessible (e.g. instead of `bootstrap.less` you actually get `404` or a sort of, hence "transferred with MIME type text/plain").

Comment: I removed this line: @import '../less/bootstrap.less'; from a css file and this error doesn't show up anymore. This is my directory structure:

File including import statement: /resources/css/home/home.css
Bootstrap Less: /resources/css/less/bootstrap.less

So, if home.css wants to import bootstrap.less, will it be correct to include a line like: import '../less/bootstrap.less'??

Comment: You can't import Less file from CSS file (CSS is handled by browser which has no notion of Less). So if you need to import `bootstrap.less` you need to do that within Less enviroment (e.g. create `home.less`, import `bootstrap.less` there and then compile this to `home.css` either on the server or in the browser).

Comment: Oh I see, could you provide a link where I can read more about it? I'm new to less and honestly do not understand how home.less would turn into home.css. All of my css rules will be in home.less right? But when does this .less file turns into .css? Where would it be stored?

Comment: Something like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=Less+CSS+tutorial) is usually a good start.